# Multiple apps with liquibase connected to one database

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-boot, liquibase

We have multiple spring boot applications (microservices) which are connecting to one database. Each application has custom db schema, for instance App A is connecting to schema_a, App B is connecting to schema_b, and so on.

These applications which are connecting to this DB is about 15 (different apps), and just about half of them started. Second half got stuck because of liquibase which is trying to run scripts, but it is waiting because of record in table databasechangeloglock which has locked set `true`. I don't understand why some apps started fine and some got stuck.

This is my datasource and liquibase configuration in each application:

```
spring.liquibase.default-schema=schema_of_app
spring.liquibase.enabled=true
spring.liquibase.change-log=classpath:xxx/changelog.xml

spring.datasource.type=com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
spring.datasource.hikari.auto-commit=false
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=20
spring.datasource.hikari.max-lifetime=60000
spring.datasource.hikari.minimum-idle=0
spring.datasource.hikari.leak-detection-threshold=20000
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/app_db?currentSchema=${spring.liquibase.default-schema}
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=pass
```

Do you have idea what I did wrong and how to fix my problem? Thank you in advice.

Comment: 15 instances of same app? or 15 different apps? You are asking for trouble if 15 heterogeneous apps are connecting to single database

Comment: @so-random-dude thank you for effort, there is 15 different apps, and each app has custom schema

Comment: You probably stopped the apps that are locked abruptly before, during the liquibase migration, thus leaving the lock in the database. Remove the lock, and restart them.

Comment: @JBNizet no I just run compose file with all my applications, there weren't any containers, volumes or anything

Comment: I don't see how the lock could be set if nothing else than the app connects to the database schema than the application you started, and the lock wasn't set before. Are you sure it does nothing except waiting for the lock to be unset? Isn't it simply applying a long liquibase migration?

Comment: @JBNizet Unfortunately there are small migrations, few tables. So multiple apps with liquibase connecting to same db but different schemas cannot caused this issue?

Answer (score 2):

What is likely happening is that while each app only updates its own schema, the Liquibase DATABASECHANGELOG and DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK tables are shared. It is likely that those tables are in the `public` schema of PostgreSQL. Rather than keeping those in the public schema, you should consider keeping separate copies of each of those two tables with the schema they are tracking. You can do this by setting the `spring.liquibase.liquibaseSchemaName` property in your configuration.

It sounds like these tables are already in existence in your databases, so you may need to do some extra steps to get them in the right places and populated correctly, and then some cleanup afterwards. This could be done with Liquibase itself, but it might be easier to do manually (depending on the number of databases involved and whether you are set up to run liquibase 'manually' rather than at application startup).

Comment: thank you I will try it. But my liquibases's tables are palced in specific schema which I define in connection string and property default-schema so there are not in public schema :/

Comment: I would double check that you have the DATABASECHANGELOG and DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK tables in the schemas you intend them to be in.